# I have SQL query how can I convert it into Laravel Query Builder format

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

**MySQL query**

```sql
SELECT
    dri_id,
    COUNT(1) AS total_rides,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN end_loc=next_start_ride THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS profit_ride
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            lead(start_loc, 1) over(PARTITION BY dri_id ORDER BY start_time ASC) AS next_start_ride
        FROM
            `drivers`
    ) a
GROUP BY dri_id;
```

Please convert it into Laravel Query Builder format.

Comment: I advise you read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are asking us to do the work for you, which is not what this platform is for. 
You can update the question to elaborate on what you've tried and why that isn't working. We are, again, not here to do the work for you.

Comment: use DB::select( DB::raw( $your_query_here ) );